# Select recently inserted record then rollback

Tags: sql, oracle, transactions, plsql, toad

I'm back in the over-complicated world of Oracle where I'd like to do the following:

- Insert a record into the database
- Select the record again
- Roll everything back

I've created the following code which fails

```
BEGIN

insert into sometable values (1, 1, 'test', 'test', 1, 'a', 1, 1, 1, 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 1);

select *
from sometable
where id = 1;

ROLLBACK;

END;
```

The error message:

```
ORA-06550: line 5, column 1:
PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement
```

I'm sure the problem is obvious, but I've checked the docs and can't gain any wisdom from them.  Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: declare a variable of type `sometable%ROWTYPE` and then select * INTO the variable.

Comment: This is the kind of curious situation where one feels obliged to ask "why?".

Comment: @DavidAldridge - Haha I can understand why you ask. It was merely so I could make the change, check I was happy with it, then remove the `ROLLBACK` as I would in SQL Server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just execute your code from SQL*Plus without BEGIN..END;

```
insert into sometable values (1, 1, 'test', 'test', 1, 'a', 1, 1, 1, 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 1);

select *
from sometable
where id = 1;

ROLLBACK;
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to put selected values to an variable 
like

```
DECLARE 
  V_COUNT NUMBER;
BEGIN

insert into sometable values (1, 1, 'test', 'test', 1, 'a', 1, 1, 1, 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 1);

select COUNT(1) INTO V_COUNT 
from sometable
where id = 1;

ROLLBACK;

END;
```

Comment: This has stopped the errors, but how do I get the value of V_COUNT to display?

Comment: SET SERVEROUTPUT ON in your IDE and then after the select in your code block add `dbms_output.put_line(v_count);`